# How to optimise styled-components at the maximum?

Tags: typescript, styled-components, tsx

I'm working on a React components library, where I use `styled-components` for styling. I was wondering how to optimise it at the maximum when dealing with dynamic styles. I see potential performance issues with them, because for every dynamic style it generates a new class and copy styles. Let's take a basic `Button` component for example:

```js
const Button = styled.button<{
    $color: "red" | "blue"
    $size?: "default" | "small" | "large"
}>`
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: ${({ $color }) => $color};
    font-size: ${({ $size }) =>
        $size === "large" ? 18 : $size === "small" ? 14 : 16}px;
    padding: ${({ $size }) =>
        $size === "large"
            ? `6px 12px`
            : $size === "small"
            ? `2px 4px`
            : `4px 8px`};
    color: white;
`

<Button $color="red" $size="small">
    Red
</Button>

<Button $color="blue" $size="large">
    Blue
</Button>
```

Here, the generated CSS looks like this:

```css
.jaVbVv {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    color: white;
}

.imDUjV {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    color: white;
}
```

Which is fine when having two buttons, but that will rarely be the case on a production app...

I've read some articles saying to use CSS variables, like this:

```js
const ButtonWithVariables = styled.button`
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: var(--button-color);
    font-size: var(--button-font-size);
    padding: var(--button-padding);
    color: white;
`

<ButtonWithVariables
    style={{
        ["--button-color" as any]: "red",
        ["--button-font-size" as any]: "14px",
        ["--button-padding" as any]: "2px 4px",
    }}
>
    Red
</ButtonWithVariables>

<ButtonWithVariables
    style={{
        ["--button-color" as any]: "blue",
        ["--button-font-size" as any]: "18px",
        ["--button-padding" as any]: "6px 12px",
    }}
>
    Blue
</ButtonWithVariables>
```

The generated HTML & CSS look like this:

```html
<button class="sc-kplVBS fGpujW" style="--button-color:red; --button-font-size:14px; --button-padding:2px 4px;">Red</button>
<button class="sc-kplVBS fGpujW" style="--button-color:blue; --button-font-size:18px; --button-padding:6px 12px;">Blue</button>

element.style {
    --button-color: red;
    --button-font-size: 14px;
    --button-padding: 2px 4px;
}

element.style {
    --button-color: blue;
    --button-font-size: 18px;
    --button-padding: 6px 12px;
}

.fGpujW {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: var(--button-color);
    font-size: var(--button-font-size);
    padding: var(--button-padding);
    color: white;
}
```

But won't this bring a readability issue? In any case the CSS variables will be used as props so I will be the only one dealing with them, so the developer experience is not an issue here.

The other idea I had was to extends styles like this:

```js
const BaseButton = styled.button`
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
`

const ButtonColor = styled(BaseButton)<{ $color?: "red" | "blue" }>`
    background-color: ${({ $color }) => $color};
`

const ExtendedButton = styled(ButtonColor)<{
    $size?: "default" | "small" | "large"
}>`
    font-size: ${({ $size }) =>
        $size === "large" ? 18 : $size === "small" ? 14 : 16}px;
    padding: ${({ $size }) =>
        $size === "large"
            ? `6px 12px`
            : $size === "small"
            ? `2px 4px`
            : `4px 8px`};
`

<ExtendedButton $color="red" $size="small">
    Red
</ExtendedButton>

<ExtendedButton $color="blue" $size="large">
    Blue
</ExtendedButton>
```

Which generates:

```html
<button class="sc-kUmlZZ sc-hbOKPk sc-chkZFb bfrZDO ebrGzz kWSVLY">Red</button>
<button class="sc-kUmlZZ sc-hbOKPk sc-chkZFb bfrZDO jXfrEy hRFOXL">Blue</button>

.hRFOXL {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}

.jXfrEy {
    background-color: blue;
}

.kWSVLY {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

.ebrGzz {
    background-color: red;
}

.bfrZDO {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
}
```

So what would be the best solution here? Having more classes or just using the variables? Maybe a mix of both with truly dynamic styles only for variables? For example a `background-image` as variable and the rest as classes?

Thanks for your answers!